# How to monitor daily costs of Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was looking around to learn about Do and Don'ts of Amazon S3 and was looking at options on how to monitor usage daily. I have couple of questions here:

1. I see on the [Amazon S3 pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) that PUT, COPY, POST, or LIST Requests are $0.005 per 1,000 requests

I have 5 buckets in S3 and each of these buckets have sub folders having 100k files.

If I do `aws s3 ls --recursive` will I be charged 
5*100k=500000/1000 = 500*0.005 = $2.50?

2. Any suggestions on tools that can be used to email daily usage rate of my S3 bucket?

Comment: how many subfolders you have?

Answer (score 3):

A `LIST` request can return up to 1000 objects. Therefore, to obtain the full list of 100k objects, it would require 100 `LIST` requests. That would consume a tenth of the initial $0.005 charge.

If you were to repeat this for 5 buckets, it would require 500 `LIST` requests, which would consume of half of the initial $0.005 charge.

Alternatively you could use [Amazon S3 Storage Inventory](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily/weekly CSV file that contains a list of all your objects. It is charged at $0.0025 per million objects listed (per bucket per run).

I sense that you are **worried about your Amazon S3 costs**. You can configure billing alerts and notifications to remain aware of when your costs rise above expected levels. This works for all AWS services.

See:

- [Monitoring Charges with Alerts and Notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/monitor-charges.html)
- [Create a Billing Alarm to Monitor Your Estimated AWS Charges](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply John. so just to confirm i will be paying $2.5 for listing all the 500k objects right?

Comment: Based upon my above logic, you could list *10* buckets @100k objects each, requiring 10 x 100 = 1000 `LIST` requests, costing a total of 2.5c

Comment: John i am very confused here... the cost should be 500LIST *0.005$ = 2.5$ right not 2.5c?

Comment: The price is **$0.005 per 1,000 requests**. 500 LIST @ $0.005 per 1000 requests = $0.005 (minimum price). (Sorry I got it wrong -- I said 2.5c, but is is actually 0.5c. And certainly not $2.50.)